# Limit order book: Data structure to maintain buy/sell order list

Tags: data-structures

I want to build a limit order book, which contains buy/sell order list. For buy order list highest buying value should be at first in list and for sell order list lowest selling value should be at first in the list. For newly coming order, I want to get its right place to insert in the list.

Currently I am using *linear search* to insert, but it takes **O(n)** time which is very high for millions of order.

Is there any **data structure which can insert the node in sorted linked list in O(log n) or less time?**

Comment: The appropriate data structure is a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Since you are only concerned about maintaining a single value (min or max) at the top, so use Max-Heap and Min-Heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> insert the node in sorted linked list in O(log n) or less time?

No that is not possible.

However you can use a **binary search tree** or a **min heap** (if you want only the min or max at a time) to store the data. A balanced binary search tree would keep your data sorted as well as make insertion/deletion in **O(log n)** time.

Comment: Use of heap will add amortized cost for dynamic array.